# NGINX as a reverse proxy based on domain / URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have three servers available behind a firewall and want to set up NGINX on one (port 80/443) to handle all http traffic to and from the others.  For the sake of simplicity, the NGINX box is at:
10.0.0.10
and the other servers are at:
10.0.0.11 and 10.0.0.12

I have Tomcat serving http on all 3 servers on port 8080.
I would like to redirect any incoming traffic destined for https://server1.myservers.com to Tomcat on 10.0.0.10, https://server2.myservers.com to Tomcat on 10.0.0.11 and https://server3.myservers.com to Tomcat on 10.0.0.12.

What is the correct NGINX configuration for that?  I realise there's more to it with a complete setup for redirection to Tomcat, my main interest is how to configure the proxy pass entries in the nginx.conf to look at the URL and make a call based on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part of the [documentation for virtual servers](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/managing-configuration-files/#virtual-servers) are you having trouble with?

Comment: This is not a site for hiring developers/administrators. We are happy to help you solve a problem if you demonstrate that you have made a reasonable attempt to resolve the problem yourself and are capable of understanding the answers given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I need the following server section repeated 3 times, one for each TLD I need to proxy:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  server1.myservers.com;
  # pass request
  location / {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   }
}
```

And of course the proxy_pass is updated to reflect the location of the server location in relation to the proxy.